# Regular Expression for Arabic words in python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, frequency, arabic, word-frequency

I use python 2.7 and i want to find the frequencies of the words in text file , 
I write a code using this following expression but there is no output :

```
    import nltk
    import os
    import re
    import string
    path="C:\Python27\Lib"
    os.chdir(path)
    frequency = {}
    document_text = open('1.txt', 'r')
    text_string = document_text.read().lower()
    match_pattern = re.findall(r'^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669 ]+$', 
    text_string)

    for word in match_pattern:
         count = frequency.get(word,0)
         frequency[word] = count + 1

    frequency_list = frequency.keys()

    for words in frequency_list:
         print words, frequency[words]
```

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: you need to paste 1.txt here

Comment: this is my input : 
بطيبـةَ رسـمٌ للرسـولِ ومعهـدُ
منيرٌ ، وقد تعفو الرسـومُ وتهمـد
ولا تنمحي الآياتُ من دارِ حرمـةٍ
بِها منبرُ الهادي الذي كانَ يصعـدُ
وواضحُ آيـاتٍ، وباقـي معالـمٍ
وربعٌ لهُ فيـهِ مصلـىً ومسجـدُ
بِها حجراتٌ كانَ ينـزلُ وسطهـا
منَ اللهِ نـورٌ يستضـاءُ، ويوقـدُ

Comment: You are matching consonants but not vowels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you do not match all characters.If you remove anchors you will get a match.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uRdqZj/2